# How can I know whether user clicked on notification or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

[my tried way](https://gist.github.com/amarjeet045/5ff77a8f6ec8af75d7cf5d0bd83b77cd)I am trying to know when i am sending push notification to users they will open the notification or not. i am able to get the number of sent notification or number of successful and failed notification but i am unable to get the user response record.I am using aws sns push notification with fcm

Answer (score 0):

it's easy!

Just put a little code in notification code, when user clicked the notification it gets the value from the database which is 0 when you start sending the notification, and add +1 in it and again store that value in the database.

This is the simple way you can check how many people open your notification.

Regards,
Sameer Rehman

Comment: how should i know the user is clicked or not?

Comment: How can i do it will you please explain?

Comment: For the better understand I will recommend the video to you, just search this title on youtube #8 Android Notification Tutorial - Handling Clicks by simplified coding .

Comment: can you send me the link

Comment: In  my case notification works fine but I only want to know how many people clicked the notification and i don't know what i pass in the parameter to know people opened the notifciation.

Comment: here is the link man https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH7DF-qDKcc&t=22s

Comment: brother in my case my notification working fine and i am able to send the user on the app.i just wanted to know how many users opened the app